# Flutter release APK：Invalid keystore format with Linux(deepin)

Tags: android, flutter

I try release APK with Flutter,but went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> Failed to read key key from store "/home/jerome/key.jks": Invalid keystore format

My storePassword and keyPassword is right.[image]

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue as well. I'm using android studio.

I unnecessarily installed a java JDK and used that to generate a keytool, which is incorrect because you are supposed to use the one provided from Android Studio.

Steps:

- `flutter doctor -v`
- Should see a `Java binary at:` under Android toolchain, this is the dir where your keytool is location, mine was `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`
- Replace `java` with `keytool` so in this case `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool`
- Run it directly, in my case I ran `/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key`
- Follow prompt
- The key.jks file will appear in your main dir. Normally somewhere in `/Users/<username>/key.jks`
- Now build your android app with this keytool should solve your problem

Comment: Same for React Native. I used: $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/keytool

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's really important to generate the keystore with a very particular version of the `keytool` executable. On my Windows machine, a search for `keytool.exe` yielded lots of results:

```
c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\jre\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\keytool.exe

c:\ProgramData\Sony Mobile\Update Engine\{5152617D-088D-4700-97C9-A2696A37E999}\jre\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Users\All Users\Sony Mobile\Update Engine\{5152617D-088D-4700-97C9-A2696A37E999}\jre\bin\keytool.exe
```

For my React Native application, I initially created the keystore with `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\keytool.exe` assuming that this would the be most authorative Java installation, and got the `"Invalid keystore format"` error.

**The solution** was to go with `c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe`. The rationale behind this would be to use the same Java installation as the build engine (in my case - `gradlew bundleRelease`).

*(Copy pasted my answer from here: [How to solve invalid keystore format in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70054462/4151043))*

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue as well using VSCode.

Choicodes answer solved the issue, then running
% flutter build appbundle --release

Produced the aap required for production in Play store console