# How to solve invalid keystore format in android studio?

Tags: android, flutter

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Failed to read key key from store "/Users/klien/klien/document/key.jks": Invalid keystore format

Comment: I answered a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988452/flutter-release-apk-invalid-keystore-format-with-linuxdeepin/66911415#66911415), hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's really important to generate the keystore with a very particular version of the `keytool` executable. On my Windows machine, a search for `keytool.exe` yielded lots of results:

```
c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\jre\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\keytool.exe

c:\ProgramData\Sony Mobile\Update Engine\{5152617D-088D-4700-97C9-A2696A37E999}\jre\bin\keytool.exe

c:\Users\All Users\Sony Mobile\Update Engine\{5152617D-088D-4700-97C9-A2696A37E999}\jre\bin\keytool.exe
```

For my React Native application, I initially created the keystore with `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\keytool.exe` assuming that this would the be most authorative Java installation, and got the `"Invalid keystore format"` error.

**The solution** was to go with `c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool.exe`. The rationale behind this would be to use the same Java installation as the build engine (in my case - `gradlew bundleRelease`).

*(Copy pasted my answer from here: [How to solve invalid keystore format in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70054462/4151043))*